# Is there a Stack Exchange site for R-related questions only?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site for question about [R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_%28programming_language%29) (the statistics software) only?

Comment: What *R*......?

Comment: OH, I see! And I read "R-rated" in the title... ;-)

Comment: @ChristianRau believe it or not, but [there is actually a proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62814/sexuality) with "R-rated" stuff...

Comment: Statistical stuff lands on cross-validated

Answer (score 15):

Short answer: no, there isn't.

But you can post questions about R on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I hate StackOverflow, it is literally overflown all sorts of question about all types of programminge language which I am not interested in. It is a very mess site with too many questions posted too fast. I can post a question, and it will be on the second page within an hour and no one will ever read it.

Comment: @Kuromusha - but the people who are interested in R questions will be monitoring the R tag for new questions. There _is_ organisation there, if you bother to look for it.

Comment: @Kuromusha nobody is forcing you to use it. But that's the only site in Stack Exchange that fits the kind of questions you're interested in. You can just monitor [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and never visit the homepage.

Comment: @Kuromusha You might also want to take a look at [Cross Validated.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/r/info). Depending on what exactly your question involves, it _might_ be on-topic there.